# upgrade from leopard to snow leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade to Snow Leopard without a CD drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/35108/upgrade-to-snow-leopard-without-a-cd-drive)

I have a mac mini with intel core 2 duo processor(2 GHz) and 1 GB of RAM. I have Leopard 10.5.8 Mac OS X installed in it. Now i want to upgrade my system to Snow Leopard (latest version). What are the steps to do it. I dont have a CD/DVD drive..

Please help me with detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Backup your system as best you can.

Do a repair disk permissions from disk utility

Install the disk and install the upgrade.

You might want 2Gb of ram though; 1gb is pushing it.