# How to install ISO format windows 7 on Mac Mini with boot camp

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

I learned how to install/upgrade snow leopard without a install CD [here](https://superuser.com/questions/35108/upgrade-to-snow-leopard-without-a-cd-drive). I was wondering if there's any way that I can install Windows 7 on Mac Mini without install CD. Say if the Windows 7 is in .iso format. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried that method, but using the Windows disk image instead of the OSX disk image?

Comment: Tried, get the error: Restore Failure, 
Could not validate source - error 254

Comment: I also use DMGConverter converting .iso to .dmg, but still can restore the dmg to a new partition on HD.